# Why Does Business Intelligence Studio Load Reports Faster than the Report Server

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services

In Visual Studio 2008 Business Intelligence Studio, reports preview many times faster than on the report server.  Why does this happen and is there a solution to this?

Comment: It looks like it is related to browser version.  If anybody finds the optimal settings for IE and ReportViewer it would be great if you would post it here:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1025852-150-1.aspx
I tested this with Firefox 5 and IE8.  Firefox loads the reports in question in about 1/20th of the time it loads in IE.

Comment: Post it here.. not at the link.  The link is a reference to others working with this issue.

Comment: Just an FYI google chrome is a lot faster then IE for reporting services as well.  Kind of odd being rs was written by / maintained by MS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In BIDS, it holds a cache, so that the query is not executed every time you preview the report. So it seems fast, however on the reportserver it will need to get all of the data for the report with every request (unless it is cached).

Rendering might also be an issue, IE does not have the best reputation on rendering speed vs. other browsers.

Comment: I verified that the issue is occurs in IE 8 vs. Firefox 5 in my situation running the same report side-by-side one after another.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/31c6f587-6c1f-4ee5-b529-5e3ed4c8d3c8 .

These reports are rendered through a ReportViewer in a web page so I would like to know ideal document settings for IE browsers to specify in the html page.  The differences in laod time are quite stark.  Firefox loads in about 20 seconds and IE takes about four minutes.

Comment: I would not know any ideal document settings for IE, and I don't think there are any. IE9 vs. IE8 already helps a lot with the rendering speed. It is pure the browser. I don't know your company rules on software and browsers, but you can advise your reporting users to upgrade or use IE9. I don't know any actual numbers on IE8 vs. IE9.

Comment: I appreciate your help with this.  I will advise to ensure they are running the latest version.